# Make the IDE ask before stopping current debug session

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode10

Once upon a time many months ago, maybe years ago, I inadvertently accepted the IDE suggestion to stop the current running debug session/s before starting the new session (on clicking the *play* button).

Do you know how to make the IDE ask again that modal dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this button in Xcode Preferences:

[image: Reset warnings]